# What reply should be given after my resignation is accepted?

Tags: resignation, human-resources

I am a bit confused about how I should reply after my resignation has been accepted. Following message, which I got from HR, how should I respond?

> Dear Umer,
>
> This is to confirm acceptance of your letter of resignation. We wish
>   you the best of luck in your future endeavors.

Comment: I don't think any reply is required, though you might still need to sort out some details (finishing date, etc.)

Comment: Every exchange of letters has to end with a letter that does not require a reply. The quoted letter looks like one of those.

Comment: I would reply with one word "Thanks" and that's it, but that's just me. I like having the last word.

Answer (score 9):

> What reply should be given after my resignation is accepted?

There's no further reply necessary.

You do want to find out the company's plan for your notice period, an exit interview (if required), and your final turnover day. That's probably a discussion with your boss, rather than with HR.

Answer (score 4):

None is required unless the letter states that confirmation is needed as part of your company's HR leavers process.